# Name for a function mapping time slices to probabilities

Tags: probability, distributions, stochastic-processes

Is there a commonly used name for a function that maps time slices in a day to probability of a specific event happening in that slice? I was using probability distribution but I guess since the total of y values can be as large as the number of time slices (i.e., this event happens at every time slice) this is misusing the terminology.

Comment: Could you clarify how you think the terminology would be misused? I couldn't follow what you were saying.

Comment: @Glen_b, I got confused because in a prob. dist. the sum of probabilities equal to 1. In this case it will be greater than 1.

Comment: @perreal, the cumulative probabilities should converge to 1, but *conditional* probabilities don't have to naively sum to 1. IE, the probability of an event in the 1st interval might be .8, and the probability of an event in the 2nd time interval, *given that it didn't occur earlier* can also be .8. These would 'sum' to 1.6, but that's just nonsense. This is a simple & common example of survival analysis w/ discrete time & an exponential distribution. Is this related to what you're getting at?

Comment: @gung, in my case an event can occur in time slice 1 with prob. 1. It can also occur in time slice 2 with the same prob. like heart beat.

Comment: There's the related concept of [hazard function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_function#hazard_function), although these probabilities are conditioned on the event not happening up to time t (i.e.: given that the event has not occurred from time 0..t-1, this is the probability of it occurring at time t).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification; you should probably edit to include the additional clarification in the text of your question.

This is basically asking 'What do I call the function describing $P(Y=1|X=x)$?' ... (as one might do for example in a logistic regression or a probit model or whatever) where in this case the x's identify your time-slices.

There are various names for such a thing; you're right that it's not normally called a distribution*. If I wanted a general name I'd probably call it a response function or the probability response function. But in different contexts people would call it other things (the conditional mean, for example).

*However there is a close connection to a conditional distribution; specifically a Bernoulli distribution is completely specified by its parameter, $p$, which is $P(Y=1)$. In that sense, $P(Y=1|X=x)$ can be seen as specifying a conditional distribution.